# WSL libcuda is not a symbolic link

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

When I do an update with Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL I get the following message:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 15):

I have the same issue, but to be honest, I haven't tried this suggested fix yet.  I've just been living with it for now.  It's a harmless message, really.

You can find the open [WSL issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5548) for more reading, but to summarize:

- As one of the WSL developers says in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5548#issuecomment-688400546):

  > mucking your System32 is not recommended for lots of good reasons

  Which I agree with, and is mainly the reason I haven't tried the recommended fix below.
- Several of the suggested fixes there cause issues with CUDA development, so I haven't tried those either.
- The [primary fix](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5548#issuecomment-912495487) seems to be to delete `libcuda.so` and `libcuda.so.1` from `C:\Windows\System32\lxss\lib` as an Administrator in Windows (not from WSL).

  Then, in WSL:

  ```
  sudo ln -sr /mnt/c/Windows/System32/lxss/lib/libcuda.so.1.1 /mnt/c/Windows/System32/lxss/lib/libcuda.so.1
  sudo ln -sr /mnt/c/Windows/System32/lxss/lib/libcuda.so.1.1 /mnt/c/Windows/System32/lxss/lib/libcuda.so
  ```

  I've made some slight (untested) changes to the commands above to (a) use `sudo` (which is required), and (b) use fully-qualified paths and the `ln -r` option.  This just means you don't need to `cd` to the directory ahead of time.  If there are any problems with the version I provided, fall back to the instructions in that post.

Comment: If it is harmless, I will let it be!

Comment: @ThomasJerry Certainly agreed there!  Since I seem to have answered your question, don't forget to upvote and accept when you get a chance.  The upvote won't "seem" to do anything until you get 20 rep, but it will be stored.  Thanks!

Comment: I followed this guide here:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5663#issuecomment-1068499676
Which gives a similar solution than the original answer, but using mklink from the windows cmd terminal, instead of WSL's ln.

Comment: You need to do it with mklnk in a cmd window and not with ln inside of wsl, because the filesystem /usr/lib/wsl/lib is mounted read-only inside of wsl.  You could possibly remount it as rw, make the links, then remount it ro, but doing it in windows is closer to the "right" way

Comment: In my case the change becomes reverted by the system, after each nvidia driver update

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution works for me :

- Open cmd as Administrator and cd into C:\Windows\System32\lxss\lib
- Delete libcuda.so and libcuda.so.1 (You can also do this in Windows Explorer as well)
- Run wsl -e /bin/bash in cmd and you should already in /mnt/c/Windows/System32/lxss/lib, now you have permission to create symlink:

  ln -s libcuda.so.1.1 libcuda.so.1

  ln -s libcuda.so.1.1 libcuda.so

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  Yes, that's the solution I mentioned in my answer that *isn't recommended* by the WSL team ;-).

Comment: this worked for me - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the solution at https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/wsl2-libcuda-so-and-libcuda-so-1-should-be-symlink/236301

```
cd /usr/lib/wsl/lib
sudo rm libcuda.so libcuda.so.1
sudo ln -s libcuda.so.1.1 libcuda.so.1
sudo ln -s libcuda.so.1 libcuda.so
sudo ldconfig
```